# How can I assign a mesh group to an armature?

Tags: animation, mesh, armature

I have a mesh group which is not allowed to merge but has to move together.  Now I am assigning each part to the same armature which controls all the parts together. It takes insanely amount of time to connect every single peace to the armature. I really wish I can just connect a group to an armature. Is this possible? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. Select all your mesh group
2. Then select your armature
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
4. Select `Parent with Automatic Weighting`

Now your mesh should be linked and moves with your armature nicely.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Tak but this is what I have tried. After press Ctrl+P I still has to assign the each vertex group to the armature in edit mode, otherwise it won't connected together, isn't it?...?

Comment: @Poa no, after pressing Ctrl+P then choosing Automatic weighting, it will automatically create vertex groups and assign vertices with weights to them.

Comment: I just followed what you said, and it ended up all parts in the group moving slightly different :( so they detached during the animation. It doesn't happen only when I make them with empty group. :/

Comment: @Poa Could you provide your file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and post the link to be able to have a look and help you?

Comment: Here I uploaded. The file could be really messy ^^;;  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3208" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3208/)

Comment: @Poa I've checked the file but it's hard to understand what you want to do. Before following the steps mentioned in my answer, go through each mesh in your mesh group and clear parents and delete all armature modifiers, then follow the above steps and see how it goes.

Comment: yes I did, and I found my model is really bad (which exported from Rhino) and the groups were totally messed up. :/  I'm modeling again in blender now and will go through your steps again. I will let you know if I succeed! Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Poa no worries, let me know how you go.